# How to print a 4 digit hexadecimal value in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
my $hex = sprintf('%X', oct("0b$reverse_str"));
print FOUT "HEX FORMAT: $hex\n";
```

If the hexa value is `007E`, it is printing only `7E`. How to get a 4 bit hexa value printed in Perl?

Comment: This is documented in [`perldoc -f sprintf`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf)

Comment: What behavior do you want if the number is > ffff

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `%04X` instead of `%X`.